# Why has the community not voted on this question?

Tags: discussion

The question [What is the point of studying so much?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/73842/what-is-the-point-of-studying-so-much) would have been shut down as either "duplicate" or off topic anyway.

Really, I've seen worse, and it was my understanding that the mods don't step in unless it's obvious spam or abusive.  As this was neither, why was it shut down by a mod?

Comment: This could probably benefit from an [edit] to make it a bit less abrasive.

Comment: @enderland by your command.  Sorry, abrasive is my "default" setting.  I don't always realize just how much so until it's pointed out.

Comment: Somehow, I doubt this will get an answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: @Lumberjack not helpful, very condescending.

Comment: @RichardU I linked those posts because they are both relevant to your question.  No disrespect intended.

Comment: Sad, I just read the question for the first time and it took me all of 30 seconds to formulate an excellent and incisive answer for the OP which would have left him/her in no doubt about the matter. But que sera sera.... I'm almost tempted to edit it to suitability just so that my 30 seconds isn't wasted.

Comment: @Kilisi if you can edit a closed question to make it fit the site (and without going against the OP's intent), then not only is that ok but it's *preferable*. We'd rather fix the question and provide helpful answers than just send it away.  Please go ahead and edit.

Comment: @Lumberjack I apologize to you too.  I can only blame an exceedingly bad mood.  No excuse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of my perspective here as a moderator for almost two years now (woah, where did that time go).

I normally do not cast unilateral votes on questions here unless they are blatantly off topic. This question fits that category, however, and notice there are no reopen votes there, suggesting a fair bit of agreement.

I *tend* to avoid doing any moderation action which can be done via the community. As you are probably aware, there are a lot of questions which are *sort of but not really but kind of? maybe, hard to tell* on topic here. I do not like to take unilateral action in those cases and as far as I can tell, neither do any of the other moderators.

Regarding closing, I am careful to avoid over moderation in edge cases. Ultimately as moderators we don't set the community scope, but we do play a role in shaping it.

Though I did [run for moderator listing a "con" of](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election/2#post-31842):

> I will be hands on and willing to close/edit questions which are off topic and add notices to answers equally falling short

I rarely get a chance to even do this though because folks here are so vigorous in closing stuff that off topic.

Also, all of us moderators are here because we love the site - it's important to me to answer, too :-) I like reading stuff here most of the time and sometimes that results in seeing questions that are blatantly off topic. I (and other moderators) occasionally will close in this scenario, as you see here.

The dangers with moderators unilaterally closing things are twofold:

1. The community comes to depend on moderators for all close voting moderation
2. Moderators close questions the community feels should be on topic

Both these are non-issues here, though, as Workplace as a community handles (1) well and as moderators I would like to think we only ever unilaterally close questions in situations like this when they are blatantly off topic.

Comment: Just a note, this is my perspective - I'm not trying to speak for Jane about this particular question, but sort of just rambling my thoughts on the situation and question you are asking.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer. I mean that sincerely.  You've given me new insights.

Comment: @enderland I've apologized to others, and you deserve one as well.  I'm sorry I went off hot-headed about this one.  I was wrong, and I apologize.

Comment: @RichardU no worries and I appreciate the honesty!

Answer (score 8):

"Mods don't step in until the community votes on it" is something that the moderators *voluntarily* agreed to follow, it is not a rule. Mods are under no obligation to follow a rule they set for themselves, even if you have come to expect it.

In this case, the question was blatantly off-topic. The mod did the right thing by closing the question right off the bat, thus saving some precious time of four other members.

By the way, a closely related feature request has been pending on meta.SE for ***over 6 years!*** ([Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/202356)) In some of the more borderline cases, moderators would find this feature useful. FWIW, if you agree with that feature request, please upvote it, it may nudge SE to implement it sometime soon. :-)

Comment: So....  Why should we bother voting then?

Comment: @RichardU err, for the other 99.9% of cases?  Mods rarely act unilaterally; we only do it when we're sure.  If a question is blatantly off-topic, what possible benefit could there be to leaving it open?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Please allow me to apologize to you as well.  I'm not going to delete this question because it's a good example of a bad example.  I went off hot-headed and I apologize to all the mods for my bad judgment and hot=headedness.

Comment: @RichardU apology accepted.  I'm glad Jane and enderland were able to clear up the confusion for you.  If you have a question about site policy or mod actions please do bring it to meta, though if you're really upset you might want to wait a bit. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio  "Act in haste repent in leisure"   I think I've learned my lesson.

Comment: @RichardU FWIW, I also apologize for some of my snide-ish remarks. I have now removed them from the answer and the comments.

Comment: @MaskedMan No worries, I deserved it.  :D   apology accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Forgive the tardiness of my reply, I'm on a completely different timezone from the US and it's early morning for me now and only just now woke up to see this one.

As mods, it's very rare that we act unilaterally.  You could count on one hand the number of times that I've done it in the year or so since I was elected.  We are conscious that we have capacity to do so, so we tend to let other community members set a voting pattern before we act.

However, please understand that we are still *members* of the community.  First and foremost we are a part of this community.  If it were not the case, we would not have the capacity to ask or answer questions, or to upvote or downvote, and yes, to vote to close or delete questions.  It is by no accident that Stack Exchange's moderation model is based on the community electing moderators from its own member base.  Long before any of us were moderators, we were - and are - community members.

So there are on occasions we we see something that we *as community members* see and understand from our own experience as part of this community that we would vote to close because they clearly are off topic and that other members would also vote to close.  We aren't closing them because we are a moderator, but because we are a member of this community and we feel the same desire to maintain a high standard of quality questions and answers.

Enderland's excellent answer is very much in synergy with my approach so I can't really add anything to it beyond what I've said.  I haven't had my morning coffee yet, so  I hope I've managed to clarify my actions a little :)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Time for me to eat a bit of crow, I suppose.  It probably has not come across with the tone of my post, but I do have a great deal of respect for the job you moderators do, so that was a bit jarring.  I now realize that the ***reason*** it was jarring is because I had not seen it before.  Upon reflection this proves your very point.  I would like to extend a personal apology to you.  I'm sorry.  I was a hothead, and I was wrong.

Comment: @RichardU Apology accepted :)  I'm glad I was able to articulate what I was trying to convey, which before I'd had my coffee was quite a feat! :)